# Group by Subject and Aggregate by having clause

Tags: mysql

Table Marks

```
Student_Name   Subject   Marks
      S1             English   75
      S2             English   45
      S1             Maths     90
      S3             Maths     95
      S2             Maths     40
      S3             English   85
      S1             Science   90
      S3             Science   99
      S2             Science   42
```

How to query who is having >= 90% aggregate and display subject marks as follows

```
Student_Name   Subject   Marks
      S3        Maths      95
      S3        English    85
      S3        Science    99
```

Comment: no, I want to show whose aggregate (English+Maths+Science) / 3 >= 90

Comment: Thankyou, you saved lots of time for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Marks m
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT Student_Name
               FROM Marks
               GROUP BY Student_Name
               HAVING AVG(Marks) >= 90 ) subquery
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=291717030d904a5b4cc943ec993dac4b)

Comment: It returning row of S1 also which is ((75+90+90)/3 = 85)

Comment: @srinivasy I don't believe you. Fiddle added.

Comment: Surprised! its a scenario (used for easy understanding) based on this i wrote the query for actual requirement. Really u saved my time @Akina

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregated function max()

```
SELECT Student_Name, Subject, max(Marks) as Marks 
FROM Marks 
GROUP BY Subject;
```

if you need greater or equal 90% than

```
SELECT Student_Name, Subject, max(Marks) as Marks 
FROM Marks 
WHERE Marks >= 90 
GROUP BY Subject;
```

If you need average score of all student whose average greater than or equal to  90

```
SELECT Student_Name, Subject, average(Marks) as AverageMarks 
FROM Marks 
GROUP BY Student_Name 
HAVING AverageMarks >= 90;
```

Comment: Separate (and unchanged) records from source table needed.

Comment: If the scores are 95, 95 & 70, your query will take only 95, 95 from Marks and give aggregate marks as 95%, which is wrong. Therefore, you have to take the sum of marks from all the subjects and then see if the aggregate is >= 90%.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM 
    Marks a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        Student_name, AVG(Marks) AS agg_marks
    FROM 
        Marks
    GROUP BY 
        Student_name
    HAVING agg_marks >= 90
) b
ON (
    a.Student_Name = b.Student_Name
);
```

Link to SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e3059/4

Comment: Editted the answer, please check.

Comment: Point taken. (y)

Comment: Yeah, I wrote that when I was doing aggregate through sum. It's not needed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try following Sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `marks` t1 WHERE Student_Name in (select Student_Name FROM marks group by Student_Name having AVG(Marks) > 90)
```

For each student with average marks over 90, it shows marks for all subjects of the student. The above query assumes that the average marks of all subjects needs to be considered when selecting the student

Link to SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92c8a/1/0